# Build an API using Ruby on Rails for Single Euro Payments Area payment (SEPA)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I am new for SEPA (Single Euro Payments Area) Payment integration and I want to integrate this with ROR to transfer funds with cross border payments feature.

I need to do integrate below functionality.

SEPA payment request with validations and retrive the payment status.

I am refering sepa_king gem (https://github.com/salesking/sepa_king), please suggest is it fine?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for some materials on how to get started with SEPA?

Comment: Hi Suresh, 
Yes with API documentation and steps if there are anything.
Thanks for your reply,

Comment: If you looking for api documentation and similar help then this is not the right place.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to see what constitutes an `on-topic` question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEPA is not an API. gem `sepa_king` is a tool to generate SEPA XML files that you can send to your bank for processing. This XML file will contain information about what amount of money to send to which accounts and from which account. It's your responsibility to collect beneficiary IBANs and safely store them.

Your bank may accept only specific version of SEPA XML file. Those versions are called PAIN (Payment Initiation). You should ask your bank which PAIN version to use

Comment: Thanks Ivan
I will do analysis on this.

Comment: I have updated my description could you please check and reply for queries?
Thanks